# ios memory leak using closure callbacks

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, memory-leaks

I have a Service class that keeps an array of Subservices whose role is to send back to the Service some events using 2 closure callbacks.

The service initializes the subservice objects with 2 closures that take a weak reference to the service in order to avoid a retain cycle.

```
public class T4fService {
    lazy var t4fSubServices: [T4fSubService?] = self.populateSubServices()
    let callbackOnServiceReady:  (_ isReady: Bool) -> ()
    let callbackOnBleEvent: (_ broadcastDict:  NotificationDict) -> ()

    init?(id: T4fServiceId,
      callbackOnServiceReady: @escaping (_ isReady: Bool) -> (),
      callbackOnBleEvent: @escaping CharacteristicCallback){

    self.callbackOnServiceReady = callbackOnServiceReady
    self.callbackOnBleEvent = callbackOnBleEvent
    }

func populateSubServices() -> [T4fSubService?]  {
    switch self.t4fServiceId {
    case .compassServiceId:
        return [T4fSubService( t4fBlePeripheralType: .Two4All, t4fCharacteristicUuidsArray: [T4fBleUuid.imuMagnetometerCharacteristicUuid],
                               callbackOnSubserviceReady: { [weak self] in self!.onSubserviceReady }(),
                               callbackOnBleEvent:  { [weak self] in  self!.onBleEvent}())]

func onSubserviceReady(_ isReady: Bool) {
    ...
    }
public func onBleEvent(broadcastDict: NotificationDict) {
    ...
    }
}

class T4fSubService{
    let callbackOnSubserviceReady:  (_ isReady: Bool) -> ()
    let callbackOnBleEvent: (_ broadcastDict:  NotificationDict) -> ()

    init?(t4fBlePeripheralType: T4fBlePeripheralType,
      callbackOnSubserviceReady: @escaping (_ isReady: Bool) -> (),
      callbackOnBleEvent: @escaping (_ broadcastDict:  NotificationDict) -> ()){
            self.callbackOnSubserviceReady = callbackOnSubserviceReady
    self.callbackOnBleEvent = callbackOnBleEvent
    }
}
```

But the memory graph on xcode is actually showing a retain cycle with both the service and the subservice memory leaked!!

[image]

Moreover looking at the graph it can be seen that it indicates that the instances of the Service and Subservices captured by the closures are strong which of course would cause the reference cycle. This is surprising because I actually pass a weak reference of the service to the closures. It seems just not true to me what xcode is showing me.

Is there something I'm doing wrong?

PS: If I change the closure passed to the subservice initializer this way the memory leaks disappear. Can anyone explain it?

```
callbackOnSubserviceReady: { [weak self] in self?.onSubserviceReady($0) },
callbackOnBleEvent:  { [weak self]  in self?.onBleEvent(broadcastDict: $0)}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this closure call expression:

```
{ [weak self] in self!.onSubserviceReady }()
```

The compiled code generates a closure which does not have a strong reference to `self`.

Then, the closure is invoked by `()`, the closure evaluates `self!.onSubserviceReady`.

As you know this is a method reference and it returns the method as a closure. (Let's call it a *method-closure*.)

And in Swift, all method-closures have implicit strong references to `self`, it is irrelevant if `self` was a weak reference or not. The expression `self!.onSubserviceReady` (or `self.onSubserviceReady`, when `self` is non-Optional) always returns the same method-closure, which has a strong reference to `self`.

Once invoked, `[weak self]` does not affect the evaluated result. So, when you do not make a strong reference to the closure itself, `[weak self]` has no effect but just make `self` Optional.

---

On the other hand, your closure expression:

```
{ [weak self] in self?.onSubserviceReady($0) }
```

It is a closure itself and you are not invoking the closure there. So, a new closure is generated, which has a weak reference to `self`, and the closure (which is not a method-closure!) is passed to the initializer and held in an instance property.

---

You should better always create a new weak-self closure, rather than using a method-closure, if you want to avoid leaks caused by closures.

Comment: Thanks  for the explanation, it's been very helpful. Is this behaviour about   "method-closures" documented somewhere?

Comment: I could not have found a clear explanation about the behavior in the [Swift book](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097). I may have learnt it through the Apple's dev forums, but I cannot recall or find in which threads. Sorry.